# Python 3: creating a dictionary/ adding values to a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

thanks for help in advance!

I try to simplify my problem:
I have a nested dict looking like:
after that I wrote a for loop to calculate a ratio of the nested dict values

```
d={'a' :{ '1990': 10, '1991':20, '1992':30},'b':{ '1990':15, '1991':40, '1992':50}}
for key in d:
    rate = d[key]['1990']/d[key]['1992']
    print(rate)
```

now I would like to create a new key value pair for each nested dict, so that in the end it looks like:

```
d = {'a' :{ '1990': 10, '1991':20, '1992':30, 'rate':0.33333},'b':{ '1990':15, '1991':40, '1992':50, 'rate':0.3}}
```

or creating a new dict looking like:

```
d2 = {'a':{'rate':0.3333}, 'b':{'rate':0.3}}
```

please help with the solution easiest for you, I think adding to the existing dict would be better?

thank you!

Comment: For same dictionary you can use `d[key]['rate'] = rate` in the `for` loop. For new dictionary declare a dictionary beforehand and use `d2[key]['rate'] = rate` in same loop

Comment: thanks so much! it worked in the bigger code as well!
and I tried .append and so many other things, and the solution is so easy
Im really a noob

Answer (score 2):

You can simply insert the key "rate" which has the value you've calculated:

```
d = {
    'a' :{ '1990': 10, '1991':20, '1992':30},
    'b':{ '1990':15, '1991':40, '1992':50}
}

for key in d:
    rate = d[key]['1990']/d[key]['1992']
    print(rate)
    d[key]['rate']=rate

print d
```

FYI, in case you use python2, you should do
`rate = float(d[key]['1990'])/d[key]['1992']`.

Comment: The float part is not necessary when considering, as the title says, that we use Python 3

Comment: @Damien Oh I missed it. Edited the answer. Thanks!